# Identify observations conditionally

Tags: r

> My dataset it as follows:

```
ID     Type
55523  Ref
55523  Ref
19999  Ref
19999  View
55523  Ref
33333  View
33333  View
33333  Ref
11111  Ref
```

> I would like a new dataframe that identifies ID's that have only Ref Type, and none other. I would like to retain the duplicates. The result would  be as follows:

```
ID     Type
55523  Ref
55523  Ref
55523  Ref
11111  Ref
```

> Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)

tb <- tribble(~ID, ~Type,
55523,  "Ref",
55523,  "Ref",
19999,  "Ref",
19999,  "View",
55523,  "Ref",
33333,  "View",
33333,  "View",
33333,  "Ref",
11111,  "Ref")

a <- tb %>% count(ID, Type) %>% group_by(ID) %>% count(ID) %>% filter(n == 1)

b <- tb %>% semi_join(a, by = c("ID" = "ID"))
b 
# A tibble: 4 x 2
     ID Type 
  <dbl> <chr>
1 55523 Ref  
2 55523 Ref  
3 55523 Ref  
4 11111 Ref
```

Comment: I'm sorry! I am new to stackoverflow. I do not know how that happened? I just tried to up-vote

Comment: apologies! I did not mean to, I am new with stackoverflow! I have tried to adjust it but it does not seem to be up-voting..

Comment: @nyk If you do an edit, then Kate would be able to change the voting

Comment: @Kate It is OK. The downvote has been removed. Thanks akrun for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Select ID's where `all` the `Type` values is `'Ref'`.

This can be done in base R :

```
subset(df, ave(Type == 'Ref', ID, FUN = all))

#     ID Type
#1 55523  Ref
#2 55523  Ref
#5 55523  Ref
#9 11111  Ref
```

`dplyr` :

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(ID) %>% filter(all(Type == 'Ref'))
```

and `data.table` :

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .SD[all(Type == 'Ref')], ID]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df = data.frame(
    "ID" = c(55523, 55523, 19999, 19999, 55523, 33333, 33333, 33333, 11111),
    "Type" = c("Ref", "Ref", "Ref", "View", "Ref", "View", "View", "Ref", "Ref")
    )

ref = df[df$Type == "Ref",]
other = df[df$Type != "Ref",]

ref[!ref$ID %in% other$ID,]
#      ID Type
# 1 55523  Ref
# 2 55523  Ref
# 5 55523  Ref
# 9 11111  Ref
```